# Issue with JPA transaction managment Data updated wrongly( ACID, isolation, READ COMMITTED)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jpa

I have facing very strange issues, based on my knowledge I'm not able to identify the issues how it happen.
In my application user A contains 100 in his balance and A send 50 to user B( B need to click on receive to receive the amount of 50). But before B receives it A rejected the transfer
and initiated another transfer to user C and amount is 10.

Ideally A should have 90 right.

But what happen, I see logs in server end that both reject and transfer request processed at same time. So the reject request and transfer request got the balance from table and that is 50. now reject request updated the balance 50 + 50 and A balance is 100 in table, but since transfer request holds the Object A and it contains balance 50 from that 10 transferred to C and balance is 40 which is updated. Now A has 40 in his balance which wrong..

I'm using Spring Boot, JPA, angularJS,

How I can over come these issues. How can I apply ACID methods in JPA. Just now I updated in JAPConfig

```
props.put("hibernate.connection.isolation", String.valueOf(Connection.TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE));
```

Above configuration will helps me to over come the issues.

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with isolation levels. If user B needs to accept the receiving, then the transaction (started by A) can't be committed before that. The transaction also needs to be rolled back if user A cancels the sending.

Comment: I agree with you Kayaman, but something went wrong and funds mismatched. my request is how to handle transactions is @Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class,CommonException.class},isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED) solves the problem ?

Comment: How would I know? I don't even know your code. However I'd be extremely surprised if fixing your problem was as simple as switching the isolation level.